# Haskell: How to simplify or eliminate liftM2?

Tags: list, haskell, monads

Consider the following code I wrote:

```
import Control.Monad

increasing :: Integer -> [Integer]
increasing n
    | n == 1    = [1..9]
    | otherwise = do let ps = increasing (n - 1)
                     let last = liftM2 mod ps [10]
                     let next = liftM2 (*) ps [10]
                     alternateEndings next last
    where alternateEndings xs ys = concat $ zipWith alts xs ys
          alts x y = liftM2 (+) [x] [y..9]
```

Where '`increasing n`' should return a list of n-digit numbers whose numbers increase (or stay the same) from left-to-right.

**Is there a way to simplify this?** The use of '`let`' and '`liftM2`' everywhere looks ugly to me. I think I'm missing something vital about the list monad, but I can't seem to get rid of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
increasing :: Integer -> [Integer]
increasing 1 = [1..9]
increasing n = do p <- increasing (n - 1)
                  let last = p `mod` 10
                      next = p * 10
                  alt <- [last .. 9]
                  return $ next + alt
```

Or, using a "list comprehension", which is just special monad syntax for lists:

```
increasing2 :: Integer -> [Integer]
increasing2 1 = [1..9]
increasing2 n = [next + alt | p <- increasing (n - 1),
                              let last = p `mod` 10
                                  next = p * 10,
                              alt <- [last .. 9]
                ]
```

The idea in the list monad is that you use "bind" (`<-`) to iterate over a list of values, and `let` to compute a single value based on what you have so far in the current iteration. When you use bind a second time, the iterations are nested from that point on.

Comment: I've chosen this as the accepted answer as it most closely follows the original question. However, as other answers point out below, I was really asking the wrong question, and the solution can be represented more simply.

Answer (score 8):

Well, as far as `liftM` functions go, my preferred way to use those is the combinators defined in `Control.Applicative`. Using those, you'd be able to write `last = mod <$> ps <*> [10]`. The `ap` function from `Control.Monad` does the same thing, but I prefer the infix version.

What `(<$>)` and `(<*>)` goes like this: `liftM2` turns a function `a -> b -> c` into a function `m a -> m b -> m c`. Plain `liftM` is just `(a -> b) -> (m a -> m b)`, which is the same as `fmap` and also `(<$>)`.

What happens if you do that to a multi-argument function? It turns something like `a -> b -> c -> d` into `m a -> m (b -> c -> d)`. This is where `ap` or `(<*>)` come in: what they do is turn something like `m (a -> b)` into `m a -> m b`. So you can keep stringing it along that way for as many arguments as you like.

---

That said, Travis Brown is correct that, in this case, it seems you don't really need any of the above. In fact, you can simplify your function a great deal: For instance, both `last` and `next` can be written as single-argument functions mapped over the same list, `ps`, and `zipWith` is the same as a `zip` and a `map`. All of these maps can be combined and pushed down into the `alts` function. This makes `alts` a single-argument function, eliminating the `zip` as well. Finally, the `concat` can be combined with the `map` as `concatMap` or, if preferred, `(>>=)`. Here's what it ends up:

```
increasing' :: Integer -> [Integer]
increasing' 1 = [1..9]
increasing' n = increasing' (n - 1) >>= alts
    where alts x = map ((x * 10) +) [mod x 10..9]
```

Note that all refactoring I did to get to that version from yours was *purely syntactic*, only applying transformations that should have no impact on the result of the function. Equational reasoning and referential transparency are nice!

Answer (score 3):

It looks very unusual to me to use `liftM2` (or `<$>` and `<*>`) when one of the arguments is always a singleton list. Why not just use `map`? The following does the same thing as your code:

```
increasing :: Integer -> [Integer]
increasing n
  | n == 1    = [1..9]
  | otherwise = do let ps = increasing (n - 1)
                   let last = map (flip mod 10) ps
                   let next = map (10 *) ps
                   alternateEndings next last
  where alternateEndings xs ys = concat $ zipWith alts xs ys
        alts x y = map (x +) [y..9]
```

Comment: Since `last` and `next` are then based on the same list and zipped together anyway, you could just eliminate `last` and `next` and incorporate the functionality into `alts`, e.g. `alternateEndings ps = concatMap alts ps; alts x = map ((10*x) +) [(mod x 10)..9]`

Comment: @Neil Brown: Interestingly, both camcann and I arrived at pretty much that exact solution, and did so (as far as I know) independently.

Comment: Agreed, it did end up a bit weird, hence the posting. The reason I got stuck down that dead-end was because I was trying to use the list monad as a way of dealing with the "it could be any of these" concept. But in the end my code just became way more convoluted.

Comment: eg instead of "let last = liftM2 mod ps [10]" I originally wanted something like "last <- ps `mod` 10" but I got unstuck on the alternateEndings bit.

Comment: @stusmith: Well, that is what the list monad is for! You just went overboard in this case, because there's only a single layer of expanding the number of possibilities at each recursive step. The list monad is most useful when the branching of possibilities is more complicated.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd write your code:

```
increasing :: Integer -> [Integer]
increasing 1 = [1..9]
increasing n = let allEndings x = map (10*x +) [x `mod` 10 .. 9]
               in concatMap allEndings $ increasing (n - 1)
```

I arrived at this code as follows.  The first thing I did was to use pattern matching instead of guards, since it's clearer here.  The next thing I did was to eliminate the `liftM2`s.  They're unnecessary here, because they're always called with one size-one list; in that case, it's the same as calling `map`.  So `liftM2 (*) ps [10]` is just `map (* 10) ps`, and similarly for the other call sites.  If you want a general replacement for `liftM2`, though, you can use `Control.Applicative`'s `<$>` (which is just `fmap`) and `<*>` to replace `liftMn` for any `n`: `liftMn f a b c ... z` becomes `f <$> a <*> b <*> c <*> ... <*> z`.  Whether or not it's nicer is a matter of taste; I happen to like it.<sup>1</sup>  But here, we can eliminate that entirely.

The next place I simplified the original code is the `do ...`.  You never actually take advantage of the fact that you're in a `do`-block, and so that code can become

```
let ps   = increasing (n - 1)
    last = map (`mod` 10) ps
    next = map (* 10)     ps
in alternateEndings next last
```

From here, arriving at my code essentially involved writing fusing all of your `map`s together.  One of the only remaining calls that wasn't a `map` was `zipWith`.  But because you effectively have `zipWith alts next last`, you only work with `10*p` and `` p `mod` 10 `` at the same time, so we can calculate them in the same function.  This leads to

```
let ps = increasing (n - 1)
in concat $ map alts ps
where alts p = map (10*p +) [y `mod` 10..9]
```

And this is basically my code: `concat $ map ...` should always become `concatMap` (which, incidentally, is `=<<` in the list monad), we only use `ps` once so we can fold it in, and I prefer `let` to `where`.

---

**1:** Technically, this only works for `Applicative`s, so if you happen to be using a monad which hasn't been made one, `<$>` is `` `liftM` `` and `<*>` is `` `ap` ``.  All monads can be made applicative functors, though, and many of them have been.

Comment: Hunh. You know, I somehow never realized that it was legal syntax to write operator sections like `(x * y +)`, even though the precedences do make the meaning clear. Go figure.

Comment: I wasn't aware of it either, until I wrote this :)  I had it in my code, and thought "…naah, there's no way GHC will parse that…", but I was pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's cleaner to pass last digit in a separate parameter and use lists.

```
f a 0 = [[]]
f a n = do x <- [a..9]
           k <- f x (n-1)
           return (x:k)

num = foldl (\x y -> 10*x + y) 0

increasing = map num . f 1
```